# C# NUnit 3.6.1 - Execute class test order

Tags: c#, nunit

I have been looking but found nothing clear. My question is the following one:

I have the following classes with some Tests inside each one.

```
|-TestClassA
|   |-TestA1
|   |-TestA2
|-TestClassB
|   |-TestB1
|   |-TestB2
|-TestClassC
|   |-TestC1
|   |-TestC2
```

How can I configure that when I click Run Test, the execution order is the following one for example?

```
1. TestClassB test cases
2. TestClassA test cases
3. TestClassC test cases
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of NUnit 3.7.1, this isn't currently possible.

There's an open feature request to implement this - a PR would be welcome!

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/345